# How to fix overlapping/intersecting edged?

Tags: mesh

I've been searching for a few days now on how to fix this: I'm trying to use a Boolean modifier to cut out a hole in an object - no problem! However, it is for a 3D print and I need another object to fit perfectly inside it. Therefore, the hole needs to be slightly larger. Scaling does not work because of the complex shape. My best solution so far is to use a displacement modifier on the "hole" normals. The problem is I end up with these overlapping areas that I need to clean up. Is there a better workflow solution to what I'm trying to do?

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

I 3D print models using Blender.  I use Solidify with boolean difference to create screw thread holes.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

This animation was made in Blender 2.9x but it helps convey the idea.

Use `Solidify modifier` to Increase the object cutter size by 0.1 to 0.2

[image: ani1]

Use `Boolean modifier` and difference

[image: ani2]

```
Solidify
Thickness: 0.1
Offset: 1.0
Even Thickness: 
Rim Fill: Enabled
Only Rim: Enabled
Normals: High Quality
```

This can be done with geometry nodes (but you'll have to test it out on your printer to get the right tolerances)

But here's it in geometry nodes I added a switch to use scale or extrude for creating the hole (**extrude seams to reproduce the soldifier modifier the closest**)

[image: img2]

Comment: Thanks! I believe I tried this when I was experimenting and I had a different (but similar) problem than the Extrude modifier. I will try to revisit when I have time.